# I need to use my variable in multiple functions in my component, but can't seem to access it

Tags: reactjs, graphql, formik

Here is an example of my code.

```
 let appointment


const [AddMemberTitle] = useMutation(ADD_MEMBER_TITLE_MUTATION)
  const [CreateMember] = useMutation(CREATE_MEMBER_MUTATION, {
    onCompleted: (newMemberData) => {
      setMemberId(newMemberData.CreateMember.id)

     //run some code using the Member id and the values from my Formik component and the appointment variable
    },
  })


 const onSubmit = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
 appointment = values.appointment

CreateMember({
      variables: {
        firstName: values.firstName,
        middleName: values.middleName,
        lastName: values.lastName,
        gender: values.gender,
        phoneNumber: values.phoneNumber,
        whatsappNumber: values.whatsappNumber,
        email: values.email,
        dob: values.dob,
        maritalStatus: values.maritalStatus,
        occupation: values.occupation,
      },
    })
}
 return (
//Then my jsx goes here
)
```

The rest of the code is working as expected, I just need to run the `AddMemberTitle` mutation using information that is generated after the `CreateMember` mutation runs.

I tried creating a variable at the top level of the component, and I'm able to assign a value to it in `onSubmit` but I'm unable to use it in the `onCompleted` function of `Create Member`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of (a few) solutions can be using a promise returned from the mutation calling function (`CreateMember` returned from `useMutation` hook).

You can use `await` or `.then()` syntax:

```
const onSubmit = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
  const { 
    appointment, 
    otherFormikValue,
    ...rest // assuming only CreateMember values and mutation names matching
  } = values;
  const { data: newMemberData } = await CreateMember({ variables: {...rest} });
  const { data: someData } = await InsertAppointmentMember(
    { variables: {
       memberId: newMemberData.CreateMember.id,
       appointmentId: appointment.id
  } });
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess my javascript knowledge still isn't where it should be.